# Shutdown MSSQL server from perl script DBI

Tags: sql-server, perl, odbc, dbi, shutdown

I'm writing a perl script in which **I've to shutdown my mssql server** ,do some operation and then I've to restart it.I know 1 way is to use netstat to stopt the service but I cann't use that.
So I tried installing DBI and DBD::ODBC module.I'm able to connect and execute queries by following code

```
use DBI;
my $data_source = q/dbi:ODBC:AUTOMATION_WOW64/;
my $user = q/pa/;
my $password = q/DCE/;

# Connect to the data source and get a handle for that connection.
my $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $user, $password)
or die "Can't connect to $data_source: $DBI::errstr";
my $str=$dbh->prepare("select SERVERPROPERTY('edition')");
$str->execute(); 
my @row;
while (@row = $str->fetchrow_array) {  # retrieve one row
print join(", ", @row), "\n";
}
```

but even after searching a lot **I cann't find any query using whch I can shutdown my server**.
Just wanted to know is it possible to shutdown the server from sql query .
I found one for mysql server

```
    $rc = $dbh->func('shutdown', 'admin');
```

at this link [http://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql](http://metacpan.org/pod/DBD%3a%3amysql)
please tell me if something similar to this exist for mssql server.

Comment: Can you just stop the SQL Server Windows service? The problem with the SQL `SHUTDOWN` command is that a SQL Server sysadmin may shut down the server and then discover that he can't restart it because he doesn't have the correct *Windows* permissions to start the service. So it's probably better to consider this as a Windows service question rather than a SQL Server one.

Answer (score 0):

There's a SQL command called `SHUTDOWN` - [more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188767.aspx)

Comment: I tried this earlier too but I'm getting this error on executing this command   "$dbh->prepare("SHUTDOWN [ WITH NOWAIT ] ");"  DBD::ODBC::st execute failed: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ' WITH NOWAIT '. (SQL-42000)

Comment: @decoder it's "SHUTDOWN  WITH NOWAIT"  but SHUTDOWN permissions are assigned to members of the sysadmin and serveradmin fixed server roles, and they are not transferable. I'd consider it unlike(hopefully) that perl is run with this rights.