# is it possible execute a perl script with admin rights or as a specific user?

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

I'm writing a perl script in which I've to shutdown my mssql server ,do some operation and then I've to restart it.I know 1 way is to use netstat to stopt the service but I cann't use that. So I tried installing DBI and DBD::ODBC module.
More info here :[Shutdown MSSQL server from perl script DBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338352/shutdown-mssql-server-from-perl-script-dbi)
But when I trying to shutdown my server using this command

```
$dbh->prepare("SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT ");
```

It's not working for me : 
I got this response from the community

> SHUTDOWN permissions are assigned to members of the **sysadmin and serveradmin** fixed server roles, and they are not transferable. I'd consider it unlike(hopefully) that perl is run with this rights.

So please tell me is there a way to run the above command as these users ? or what can I do other than this . Note that I have a constraint tha tI cann't simply stop it as windows service.

Comment: You do not want to add the current user to either of those groups?

Comment: I'm executing this script with "sa" user which is already member of sysadmin

Comment: Who are you connecting to the database as?  What does your DBI->connect statement look like?

Comment: use DBI;
my $data_source = q/dbi:ODBC:AUTOMATION_WOW64/;
my $user = q/sa/;
my $password = q/DCE/;

# Connect to the data source and get a handle for that connection.
my $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $user, $password)

Comment: As I commented in [your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338352/shutdown-mssql-server-from-perl-script-dbi), how are you going to start SQL Server again after you've stopped it? You'll need the correct Windows permissions in order to start the service, so this is really a question about starting and stopping Windows services. Just because you have permission to run `SHUTDOWN` within SQL Server does not mean you have permission to start the SQL Server service: `SHUTDOWN` needs SQL Server permissions, but starting the service needs Windows permissions.

Comment: @MichaelGardner `sysadmin` and `serveradmin` are SQL Server [server roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx), they are not Windows groups.

Answer (score 0):

If the scripts are executed through a web browser then the user executing the scripts will be defined by the web server. It will probably not be a good idea to fiddle with this user. Just leave things as they are.

What you can do is to create a Perl script that is being run by a privileged user on a consistent basis with CRON.

This script being run by CRON can check for specific content like a file which has been written by a script where the user executing the script has lesser privileges.

So the way it could work is as follows:

1. You execute browser.cgi through a browser to do a specific task.
2. browser.cgi writes instructions to a file.
3. Every 1 minute priveleged.cgi executes via CRON. (The root user could execute priveleged.cgi)
4. priveleged.cgi reads the file browser.cgi has written for instructions and starts and stops services according to the instructions.