# How can I stop and restart SQL Server from Perl?

Tags: sql-server, windows, perl, service

I want to stop and then restart the MSSQL service programatically using perl. But using NET STOP MSSQLSERVER prompts for stopping dependent services. What is the easiest way to do this

Comment: `NET STOP MSSQLSERVER /y`?

Comment: Please stop posting multiple questions that contradict and/or overlap each other. This question asks how to *stop* SQL Server from Perl, so `SHUTDOWN` is a perfectly correct answer, but we know from your [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338352/shutdown-mssql-server-from-perl-script-dbi) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396077/is-it-possible-execute-a-perl-script-with-admin-rights-or-as-a-specific-user) that your real goal is to *stop and restart* SQL Server from Perl, which is something completely different. I've modified the title accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As @Joachim mentioned, you can simply run `net stop` command to stop the service but to me question is say if you are stopping SQL Server service, then what are you going to do with related services e.g. SQL Server Agent ? Because without SQL Server service others depending services will not work.

So to me better solution will be to stop depending service first, e.g. `NET STOP SQLSERVERAGENT` and then `NET STOP MSSQLSERVER` and when starting them start them in reverse order.

Comment: I'm not doing this because on windows 7 it prompts for password but I've to do this automatically , and I'm not able to find any method of passing credentials along with command